# How to retrieve data settings from database array to have globally acces in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How to retrieve global settings from database table ?
I know how to create global settings in array like this:
path:

```
app/config/settings.php

<?php
return array(
        'admin_email' =>'mail@shabeebk.com',
        'admin_name' =>'Admin',
);
```

and in controller:

```
$cvalue = Config::get('settings.admin_name');
```

I'd like to achive the same effect but this time data receive from table settings

```
$data = Settings::get();
```

return as array and have globally acces to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can accomplish this, here are two options that come to mind.

## Option 1: preload

In a ServiceProvider `boot()` method (maybe your `AppServiceProvider`) you could easily load up all DB settings into config:

```
Settings::get()->each(function($setting) {
    // Assumes the columns in your DB are 'key' and 'value'
    Config::set('settings.' . $setting->key, $setting->value);
});
```

Now you can just grab `Config::get('settings.foo')` globally.

## Option 2: query as-needed

Or you could write a `get()` method on your Settings model that provides similar behavior:

```
public static function get($key, $default = null)
{
    if($match = self::where('key', $key)->first()) {
        return $match->value;
    }

    return $default;
}
```

Now you can use `Settings::get('foo')` globally.

Comment: Both answers are satisfactory. Thanks a lot.